# Merge [hana-cloud-platform] into [sap-cloud-platform]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Back in 2017, SAP has renamed the SAP HANA Cloud Platform by just removing the HANA out of the name, the new name being SAP Cloud Platform. The official announcement can be found on [news.sap.com here](https://news.sap.com/mwc-sap-cloud-platform-intelligently-connects-people-things-businesses/). The relevant quote from the announcement:

> SAP SE (NYSE: SAP) today announced the expansion of **SAP Cloud
>   Platform, formerly known as SAP HANA Cloud Platform**, with new
>   capabilities and enhancements to provide an industry-leading platform
>   as a service (PaaS).

So one way of reacting could be to just merge the old [hana-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hana-cloud-platform) tag with the new [sap-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-cloud-platform) tag to reflect this re-branding. On the other hand, the old tag is apparently more popular (85 vs. 5 questions), so maybe it makes sense to just make one a synonym of another?

Comment: For future readers: it's been renamed, again. Consider voting for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405429/5846045