# Merge [sap-cloud-platform] to [sap-business-technology-platform]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Same as [Merge [hana-cloud-platform] into [sap-cloud-platform]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369120/5846045), SAP decided, again, to replace their platform brand name.

This time: from "SAP Cloud Platform" (SCP) to **"SAP Business Technology Platform"** (SAP BTP). It was first officially announced in the middle of a blog post:<sup>[[1]](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/01/27/a-robust-platform-for-rise-with-sap/)</sup>

> In line with our goal to establish *SAP Business Technology Platform* as THE platform for the intelligent enterprise, **we decided to sunset the "SAP Cloud Platform" product name** [...]. While the actual cloud platform capabilities are renamed, [...] the products and services continue to be available, their functionality and agreements will stay unchanged.

Consequently, other tools, services, and products from SAP were renamed as well.<sup>[[2]](https://www.sap.com/documents/2021/02/bc275d93-d07d-0010-87a3-c30de2ffd8ff.html)</sup> E.g. from "SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Android" to *"**SAP BTP** SDK for Android"*.<sup>[[3]](https://developers.sap.com/topics/sap-btp-sdk-for-android.html)</sup>

Accordingly, [sap-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-cloud-platform) **and** [hana-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hana-cloud-platform) should be added as synonyms to [sap-business-technology-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap-business-technology-platform).

At the time of writing, the tag [sap-cloud-platform] can't even be proposed as a synonym because [sap-cloud-platform] itself has [hana-cloud-platform] as its synonym:
[image: synonym proposal failed due to the synonym having another synonym]

> Failed to propose synonym:
> Reverse synonym sap-cloud-platform already proposed on the tag hana-cloud-platform

Comment: The tags have been synonymised.

Comment: Clarification to avoid possible confusion: while SAP BTP unifies many SAP solutions and covers the former SCP solutions on the product level, the **technological capabilities and functionalities of SCP stay unchanged in SAP BTP.** No customer can be using "SAP Cloud Platform" today since the name is scrapped by SAP.